# Parse Errors when URL in method header

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project, I use several frameworks (Core Data, Social etc). When a framework method name contains the text "URL", a parse error is given for every occurence like this:

[image]

I have no idea what the problem is. We tried rebooting the Mac, rebooting XCode, cleaning the project and everything.

Anyone experienced this problem? There is no way I can find anything on google about this.

Comment: Sounds like `URL` has been `#define`d to some silly value somewhere.  Look through your header files.

Comment: @trojanfoe Post it as an answer, cause this fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like `URL` has been `#define`'d to some silly value somewhere. Look through your header files.